# Calculation of Feynman invariant amplitude with internal global symmetry indices: trace over\and isospin

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, scattering, feynman-diagrams, isospin-symmetry

This is a complete rewriting of the older post, making more clear the problem.

The issue here is to compute the $$|M|^2 =4a^2(\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc} - \frac{1}{2} \delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}) ^2  (u_{1b}^{\mu}\bar{u}_{1 \mu a} u^{\mu}_{1'b}\bar{u}_{1'\mu a})\\ \times(u_{2'd}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2'\nu c}u_{2d}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2\nu c}) $$
invariant Feynman amplitude, and in fact, the search for a possible, if it exists, way for writing this as a trace both on $SU(2)$ and Lorentz indices.

One of terms of the above amplitude is: $$T_1 = \delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc} \omega = 4 (u_{1b}^{\mu}\bar{u}_{1 \mu a} u^{\mu}_{1'b}\bar{u}_{1'\mu a})(u_{2'a}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2'\nu b}u_{2a}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2\nu b}),$$where $\omega $ is the series of spinors before contracting the deltas and the 4 coefficient comes from the contraction of deltas.

Question: I'm having a problem seeing how could I simplify this expression. Can I simultaneously reform this term to a trace? The possibilities are a trace over:

1. Just spin indices; but what happens then with the internal indices?
2. Internal isospin trace; but what then happens with spin indices?
3. A trace over both indices?

Thank you.

---

*Details*

Assume a Lagrangian with an interaction term of the form $L_{int}=\bar \psi \phi \cdot \tau \psi$ , globally symmetric under the action of $SU(2)$ group. Think that the field $\psi$ describes a nucleon as an isospin SU(2) doublet with entries the proton and neutron and the field $\phi$ an isospin triplet (in the adjoint representation) of SU(2) formed by the three scalar pions.

The problem is to calculate the invariant Feynman amplitude. We have, *writing all the indices explicitly*:

$$M=a(q^2) (\bar{u}_{1'\mu a}\tau^{ab}_k u^{\mu}_{1b})( u_{2'\nu c}\tau^{cd}_k\bar{u}^{\nu}_{2d}) ,$$ where $\tau_k$ are the $SU(2)$ generators; Pauli matrices and q is the interaction momentum of the propagator. The complex conjugate then is:
$$M^{*}=a^{*}(q^2) (\bar{u}_{1\mu a}\tau^{ab}_k u^{\mu}_{1' b}) (u_{2\nu c}\tau^{cd}_k\bar{u}^{\nu}_{2' d}) .$$

This way one should recognise the scalar nature over both $\mu, \nu $ Lorentz indices and over $a,b,c,d, k $ isospin indices. A similar calculation can be found in chapter 46 of Srednicki, without the extra internal symmetry and it's indices. There, it's simple then to recognise the trace over spin indices of the $|M|^2 =MM^{*} $.

For the generators there is the following completeness relation: $\tau_{ab}^k \tau_{cd}^k = 2(\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc} - \frac{1}{2} \delta_{ab}\delta_{cd})  .$

So finally, the amplitude is:

$$|M|^2 =4a^2(\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc} - \frac{1}{2} \delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}) ^2  (u_{1b}^{\mu}\bar{u}_{1 \mu a} u^{\mu}_{1'b}\bar{u}_{1'\mu a})\\ \times(u_{2'd}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2'\nu c}u_{2d}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2\nu c}) $$

The delta identity gives three terms; the first, let's say $T_1$, is:
$$T_1 = \delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc} \omega = 4 (u_{1b}^{\mu}\bar{u}_{1 \mu a} u^{\mu}_{1'b}\bar{u}_{1'\mu a})\\ \times(u_{2'a}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2'\nu b}u_{2a}^{\nu}\bar{u}_{2\nu b}),$$ where $\omega $ is the series of spinors before contracting the deltas and the 4 coefficient comes from the contraction of deltas.

Comment: What I need is a way to confirm somehow the result without having to think about non-abelian Yang-Mills theories, since this model has a global symmetry and should be easier to calculate than going to a full gauge-invariant consideration. Even if the way to treat this is to take the Lorentz trace and leave the isospin indices as they are, I could really find helpful a comment explaining and verifying such a case.

Comment: If I take the spinor trace as if I hadn't the internal symmetry, then I should have something like: $T_1 = 4 Tr[u_{1b}\bar{u}_{1a}u_{1'b}\bar{u}_{1'a}]Tr[u_{2'a}\bar{u}_{2'b}u_{2a}\bar{u}_{2b}] $. Can I then consider somehow a trace of ab indices inside it's trace?

Comment: You are free to define a trace as being over any indices you like, provided they satisfy the definition of the trace in index form. Additionally, since your SU(2) indices are spinor indices that run over $a = 1,2$, you might find the appendix in https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.1594 useful

Comment: @Akoben Thanks but I'm not sure we 're talking about the same thing; first what would you call a definition of the trace in index form, more so in relation with my example. Secondly, and mostly, the $a,b $ indices run in isospin space. Is that the same as what you call two component spinors? Thanks again.

Comment: If $\tau^{ab}$ are the Pauli matrices, then $a,b$ run over $1,2$ and you can treat the spinors as two component spinors for this symmetry. If I remember correctly, the trace is defined as $Tr(u^\dagger v) = \sum_{a,b}u^{ab}v_{ab}$ but probably best to look that up to check.

Comment: @Akoben Maybe you are correct; as I see it it, it's not like I have one Dirac spinor and I can choose to represent it as a two component spinor; I think that a=1 and a=2 accounts for two different Dirac spinors, one for the proton and one for the neutron. If I understand correctly, are you suggesting the two formalisms are equivalent?

Comment: Are you averaging over spins? if you are not, I wouldn't expect you to be able to simplify this much; your only option would be to choose a convenient frame of reference (say, $\boldsymbol p=(0,0,p)$), and use the explicit for of the $u,v$ vectors.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for your reply. I will average over spins to get that identity with the slashed momentum plus mass, but I will still carry the isospin indices; I 'll get something of the form $(\gamma^{\mu} p_{1 \mu} +m)_{ba} (\gamma^{\mu} p_{\mu 1'} +m)_{ba}... $ But is there anything I can do for the isospin indices? Thanks.