# Reference Request: Invariant Feynman amplitudes with global symmetry on Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, symmetry, scattering, feynman-diagrams

Question:

The question here regards the handling of extra indices, coming from internal (global) symmetries, in the calculation of invariant Feynman amplitudes.

---

Details:

I'm dealing with a verification problem, or at least with a matter of finding a simplification if it exists, of a certain amplitude. The case is this: like one can find in Srednicki, chapter 46, I have a scattering in the QFT context and after writing down the corresponding Feynman diagram, I get spinors which are contracted and I can conclude with a trace over spinor indices.

The key difference is that my Lagrangian possesses an internal global symmetry under the action of SU(2) group, so my spinors also have indices coming from the internal symmetry- it's equivalent to isospin. One can of course find more details on the post in the link given below.

For the case here, I would like to believe that the problem- if it can be simplified like this and a certain process can give a result over both spinor and isospin indices- can be confronted without the need of the more sophisticated techniques of helicity formalism (which I think applies to high energies) or of the techniques developed for non-abelian gauge theories(which have their symmetries as local) since it seems a global symmetry is more simple.

---

I posted a question here a while ago and I have reformulated in a much more clearer context. The question can be found here: [Calculation of Feynman invariant amplitude with internal global symmetry indices: trace over\and isospin](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363213/)

For any hints,references, or comments for the inability of such a simplification, thank you in advance.

Comment: Tip: Consider to reformulate question purely as a physics question without an explicit resource request. All questions are implicitly resource requests. Explicit res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE.

Comment: @Qmechanic I hope this edition is now better? Thank you.